# Application X has not been registered - tried suggestions per other answers

Tags: android, react-native, apk

We have been stuck with this error for couple of weeks, trying all the suggestions from answers to same question on Stack Overflow before.

[image]

We have already tried checking the app name matches in Index.js, MainActivity.js, and a parameter file we maintain called app.json.

The problem we face is 'npm start' is stuck on load dependency graph, done... message, and react-native run android generates an apk that gives 'Application SmartMedi is not registered'.

Code portions copied below.

*MainActivity.java*

```
package com.SmartMedi;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.calendarevents.CalendarEventsPackage;
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
     * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
     */
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "SmartMedi";
    }
    @Override
  public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
      CalendarEventsPackage.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
      super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
  }

}
```

*app.json*

```
    {
  "name": "SmartMedi",
  "displayName": "SmartMedi"
}
```

*index.js*

```
    /** @format */

import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './src/components/Main';
//Registration,Main,SearchScreen

import {name as appName} from './app.json';
// type Props = {};


console.disableYellowBox = true;

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "SmarMedi",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
...
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
...
    "native-base": "^2.7.2",
    "react": "16.4.1",
....
    "react-native": "^0.55.4",
.....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your package.json has `"name": "SmarMedi"`. T is missing in `SmartMedi`.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to look into the details. We fixed this name change in all files, and somehow missed package.json.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you are running the app, but you forgot to close the metro bundler opened by a previous project. Uninstall the app on simulator, restart terminal and re-run the project.

Comment: We have been trying this for past couple of weeks. Even with no other bundler running we kept getting the error. Now we know with the help of SO answer that there was a typo in package.json.

Comment: Okay. In my case that was the issue. You must wait for more answers then. Also try clearing cache once.